# Normal Curvature Along a non arclength-parameterized curve

Tags: differential-geometry

I consider the surface $S=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: \, z=x^2+y^2\}$. Clearly, it may be parameterizated by $\phi(u,v)=(u,v,u^2+v^2)$. Now, I consider the curve $t \to \phi(t^2,t)$.
Which is the normal curvature along the previous curve? My problem is that the curve is not arclength-parametrized, so I cannot compute simply the second fundamental form in the point $\phi(t^2,t)$. In this case, what can I do?

Comment: Maybe you can use Meusnier Theorem since your curve and it's positive arc length parametrisation have same unit tangent vector field at same points? I might be wrong though.

Comment: Yes, I want to use Meusnier Theorem. Have I to compute the tangent vector $v$ to the curve, then to find its norm (in order to divide for it) and finally to compute the second fundamental form on $\frac{v}{\Vert v \Vert}$?

Comment: that's how I would have done it aswell, but Meusnier is valid only for all arc length parametrised, so there might be a problem. Atleast we can surely say that for every point of your curve (whenever it's regular) there exist an arclength parametrised curve with tangential $\frac{v}{\Vert v\Vert}$ (as a normal section). And then use Meusnier. I think it's plausible.

Comment: Computations seems really cumbersome.

Comment: @user3342072 I think this is not the way to solve the exercise.

Comment: I am struggling aswell:) take a look [here](https://www.math.uh.edu/~minru/Riemann09/four1.pdf) page 8, maybe you can come up with something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still compute curvature of a non-arclength-parametrized curve; there are various ways to do it. My favorite is just to adjust the usual calculations with the chain rule. See, for example, p. 13 of [my differential geometry text](http://faculty.franklin.uga.edu/shifrin/sites/faculty.franklin.uga.edu.shifrin/files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf). So compute $\kappa\vec N$ at the point and then dot with the unit surface normal. (This is the Meusnier's formula application comments referred to.)

Alternatively, yes, evaluate the second fundamental form of the surface at $\phi(t^2,t)$ on the unit tangent vector of the curve. At $t=0$ this will be easy enough; for other values of $t$ it will be yucky algebra either way, I guess.

I can answer further questions if you ask.